# Fetching console output in App Service VM to local PC

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell

I would like to do get HTML local output `$htmlpart`. How to code in "Trying" section?

#### Steps

- Signing in the Kudu `https://(App Service name).scm.azurewebsites.net/`
- [Debug Console], [PowerShell]

  - `https://(App Service name).scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell`
- Running one-line command like as:

  - `(Get-Item D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll).VersionInfo`
- Getting result as an object and converting to `$htmlpart`

#### Expected output (in HTML format)

```
ProductVersion   FileVersion      FileName
--------------   -----------      --------
5.6.4.62175      5.6.4.62175      D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Microsoft.Data.OD...
```

#### Trying

```
$username = "(username)"
$password = "(password)"
$secpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $secpassword)
Add-AzureRMAccount -Credential $Credential
Write-Output "Done: Add-AzureRMAccount"

$appservicename = "(App Service Name)"
$command = '(Get-Item D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll).VersionInfo'

# 
# I don't know how to deploy `$command` to `$appservicename`
# `$command` includes local path (D:\ ...) in `$appservicename` VM
# 

$result = (Object shown in "Expected output" section)

$htmlpart = $result `
  | Sort-Object -property FileName `
  | ConvertTo-Html `
     -Fragment `
     -PreContent "<h4>file list</h4>" `
     -Property * `
     -As Table
```

#### Environment - `$PsVersionTable`

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, execute an arbitrary command on a `frame`? so emulate you typing?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thanks, I want to get local HTML output `$htmlpart`